# how do I separate (they are stacked over each other) and center items within a div so that there are equal spaces between them

Tags: html, css, flexbox, center, centering

I made 4 separate circles to test out conic gradients, I want to center them so that they are equally spaced, but they are all stacked over each other so they kinda just move in one unit.

my HTML:

```
 <div class="allcorners">
  <div class="corner1"> </div>
  <div class="corner2"> </div>
  <div class="corner3"> </div>
  <div class="corner4"> </div>
</div>
```

---

My CSS:

```
.c-gradients{
 margin-right:0;
 margin-left: 0;
 justify-content: center;
}
.c-gradient1{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: conic-gradient(#bcadc4,#9de3c1, #7980bd);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: auto;
  }
 .c-gradient2{
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   background-image: conic-gradient(#bcadc4 45deg,#9de3c1 90deg, #7980bd);
   border-radius: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   padding: auto;
   }

 .c-gradient3{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: conic-gradient(#bcadc4 80deg,#9de3c1 90deg, #7980bd);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute; 
  }    

 .c-gradient4{
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   background-image: repeating-conic-gradient(#bcadc4 10%,#9de3c1 25%);
   border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
 }
```

Comment: Please correct your code so that the HTML and CSS are consistent with one another and make the code into a snippet we can run - and check yourself that it shows the problem! See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with making a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 0):

just position the divs with left:xx%; also, your classes are mislabeled.  Doing things with position:absolute; should generally be avoided as it takes those elements out of the DOM sequence.  This is a good example of where to use flex instead.

```css
.allcorners{
 margin-right:0;
 margin-left: 0;
 justify-content: center;
}
.corner1{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: conic-gradient(#bcadc4,#9de3c1, #7980bd);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: auto;
  left:0;
  }
 .corner2{
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   background-image: conic-gradient(#bcadc4 45deg,#9de3c1 90deg, #7980bd);
   border-radius: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   padding: auto;
   left:25%;
   }

 .corner3{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: conic-gradient(#bcadc4 80deg,#9de3c1 90deg, #7980bd);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  }    

 .corner4{
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   background-image: repeating-conic-gradient(#bcadc4 10%,#9de3c1 25%);
   border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left:75%;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="allcorners">
  <div class="corner1"> </div>
  <div class="corner2"> </div>
  <div class="corner3"> </div>
  <div class="corner4"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: turns out I copied and pasted the wrong html section , so there was no problem with my class titles, otherwise , thanks. I struggle a lot with positioning and use "position: absolute;" all the time.